# Manipulating Mp3's as Array Using NAudio

Tags: c#, signal-processing, naudio

I'm trying to reimplement an existing Matlab 8-band equalizer GUI I created for a project last week in C#. In Matlab, songs load as a dynamic array into memory, where they can be freely manipulated and playing is as easy as sound(array).

I found the NAudio library which conveniently already has Mp3 extractors, players, and both convolution and FFT defined. I was able to open the Mp3 and read all its data into an array (though I'm not positive I'm going about it correctly.) However, even after looking through a couple of examples, I'm struggling to figure out how to take the array and write it back into a stream in such a way as to play it properly (I don't need to write to file).

Following the examples I found, I read my mp3's like this:

```
   private byte[] CreateInputStream(string fileName)
    {
        byte[] stream;
        if (fileName.EndsWith(".mp3"))
        {
            WaveStream mp3Reader = new Mp3FileReader(fileName);
            songFormat = mp3Reader.WaveFormat; // songFormat is a class field
            long sizeOfStream = mp3Reader.Length;
            stream = new byte[sizeOfStream];
            mp3Reader.Read(stream, 0, (int) sizeOfStream);
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Unsupported Exception");
        }
        return stream;
    }
```

Now I have an array of bytes presumably containing raw audio data, which I intend to eventually covert to floats so as to run through the DSP module. Right now, however, I'm simply trying to see if I can play the array of bytes.

```
        Stream outstream = new MemoryStream(stream);
        WaveFileWriter wfr = new WaveFileWriter(outstream, songFormat);
        // outputStream is an array of bytes and a class variable
        wfr.Write(outputStream, 0, (int)outputStream.Length);
        WaveFileReader wr = new WaveFileReader(outstream);
        volumeStream = new WaveChannel32(wr);
        waveOutDevice.Init(volumeStream);
        waveOutDevice.Play();
```

Right now I'm getting errors thrown in WaveFileReader(outstream) which say that it can't read past the end of the stream. I suspect that's not the only thing I'm not doing correctly. Any insights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because you never close the `WaveFileWriter` so its headers aren't written correctly, and you also would need to rewind the `MemoryStream`.

However, there is no need for writing a WAV file if you want to play back an array of byes. Just use a `RawSourceWaveStream` and pass in your MemoryStream.

You may also find the `AudioFileReader` class more suitable to your needs as it will provide the samples as floating point directly, and allow you to modify the volume.